# ¿Cómo realizo una petición a mi aplicación desde el servidor en el que se encuentra alojada?

Tags: python, django, linux, apache, deployment

Estoy intentando hacer una petición a una aplicación que tengo desplegada en un servicio apache2 configurado en una maquina virtual ubuntu server, y para hacer la petición utilizo Python. Los despliegues se hacen para que sean consumidos de manera local (solo para las personas de la red), dicha configuración del servicio apache tiene varios virtualHost pertenecientes a los despliegues de cada aplicación y su enrutamiento se mediante DNS.

Al momento de hacer la petición desde el navegador de algún equipo perteneciente a la red funciona común y corriente, el problema radica en el momento en el que intento hacer la misma petición pero estando dentro del servidor, bien sea en el navegador o ejecutando la petición por consola.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la petición se resuelva estando dentro del servidor?

A continuación dejo el error que me deja la consola del interprete de python, espero me puedan ayudar.

````
>>> import requests
>>> resp = requests.get('http://service-mails-customer.johannaortiz.local/')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/servicemailscustomer/sermacu_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 175, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/var/www/servicemailscustomer/sermacu_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known```
````

Comment: Qué sucede cuando haces (en ese host): `ping service-mails-customer.johannaortiz.local`? o `dig service-mails-customer.johannaortiz.local`. Se resuelve el nombre a una IP sin problemas?

Comment: Cuando le hago ping dice que el servicio el servicio es desconocido.

Comment: Ok.... eso apunta a que tienes un problema en el DNS. Dices que desde otros equipos no hay problema? Cual es el DNS que usan los equipos donde _si_ funciona? Y cual es el contenido del archivo `/etc/resolve.conf` de ese equipo donde estás trabajando? (ponlo como información adicional de la pregunta, no como comentario).

Comment: funciona en todos los equipos que estén conectados a la red, el problema nace al momento de hacer la petición desde el servidor donde está desplegado el desarrollo. El archivo que mencionas está limpio, lo encontré en /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suena a que tienes un problema con la configuracion de DNS del servidor, por ello fallan las peticiones de resolución de nombre de otros comandos como ping. Una forma de evitar usar el DNS (si es que no lo quieres configurar en el equipo) es fijando nombres dentro de `/etc/hosts`. En este archivo puedes asociar IPs con una multitud de nombres, evitando el uso de DNS por completo. Podrías agregar una línea como esta:

```
127.0.0.1    service-mails-customer.johannaortiz.local
```

Esto no es más que un **hack** mientras resuelves el problema del DNS para que la resolución de nombres funcione de forma adecuada. Cuando haya más información en la pregunta para dar una respuesta sobre el problema del DNS, editaré esta respuesta para incluir esa parte.

Comment: Mira que el DNS redirecciona correctamente, ya intenté con el localhost pero como todas van al puerto 80, me pregunto: si escribo requests.get('http://localhost/'), ¿Cual de todas las aplicaciones podría tomar? ya que el .conf de apache tengo configurado varios virtualHost. Me hago entender? a lo que voy es que el enrutamiento se hace mediante el serverName del respectivo virtualHost y no del puerto.

Comment: No entiendo qué quieres decir con _"el DNS redirecciona correctamente"_.

Comment: gracias!! funcionó!!

Comment: Excelente. Pero como digo en la respuesta: **eso es un hack**. Tendrías que arreglar la configuración de DNS de ese equipo.